# How to combine the switch statement and if case?

Tags: java, if-statement, switch-statement

I am new to java and trying to program a function that checks if the moves are valid on a board game.

B1 has A2 and C2 as valid moves.

D1 has C2 and E2, however if C2 is occupied by B1 then D1 only has E2 as a valid move.

F1 has E2 and G2, again if E2 is occupied by D1, F1 only has G2 as a valid move.

Lastly H1 only has G2 as a valid move, and no other valid move if G2 is occupied by F1.

Same rule applies to B1 if C2 is occupied by D1.

I thought of combining the switch statement with if but I do not know how to do it.

This is my code so far:

```
public static boolean isValidMove(int dim, String[] players, char figure, String origin, String dest) {
    if ((dim < 4) && (dim > 26)) 
        throw new IllegalArgumentException ("NO!");
    if (players == null) 
        throw new IllegalArgumentException ("NO!");
    if ((figure != 'F') && (figure != 'H')) 
        throw new IllegalArgumentException ("NO!");

    switch (origin) {
        case "B1":
            dest = "A2";
            dest = "C2";
            break;
        case "D1":
            dest = "C2";
            dest = "E2";
            break;
        case "F1":
            dest = "E2";
            dest = "G2";
            break;
        case "H1":
            dest = "G2";
            break;
        }

    return true;
}
```

Origin Strings are B1, D1, F1, and H1.

Comment: `((dim < 4) && (dim > 26))` —This condition can never be true.

Answer (score 0):

You may be looking for something like this:

```
switch (origin) {
        case "B1":
        case "H1":
            System.out.println("This applies to both B1 and H1");
            origin == B1 ? System.out.println("This only applies to B1) : System.out.println("This only appliest to H1)
            break;
        case "D1":
        case "D3"
        case "F1":
            System.out.println("This applies to D1, D3 and F1");
            //if....
            break;
        }

        return true;


    }
```